# WebAPI batch request filters

Tags: batch-processing, asp.net-web-api

When a batch request is made to a "Microsoft" Web-API, does every item in the batch passes by the filters or the batch passes once "as a whole"?!?

Answer (score 0):

Im very sorry if i misunderstood your question (lol), please do not mark me down.
This is an advanced topic, and if you are referring to the batch ping command, then further notes about using it can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff961503.aspx). To answer your question, **Technicaly its piece by piece (literally bit by bit) passing through the checker programs(or filters) in the computers at Microsoft. But from an executing standpoint, a piece to be executed it loaded up until complete before it is executed.** Hope i helped. PS: The ping command uses [Internet Control Message Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol).